Generalized version of the definition of an equivariant map
Let $X$ and $Y$ be $G-$spaces. A (continuous) map $f: X \to Y $ is called equivariant if $f(g \cdot x) = g \cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. In Borel's generalized definition in Seminar on Transformation Groups (1960, p. 50), given a group homomorphism $\lambda: G \to H$, where $ X $ is a $G-$space and $Y$ an $H-$space, a map $f: X \to Y$ is said to be $ \lambda -$equivariant if $f(g \cdot x) = \lambda(g) \cdot f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. I’ve been searching for references that discuss this more general form of equivariance, but I haven’t found any. Could anyone suggest relevant texts?

So I suppose this is more general than treating $X$ and $Y$ as $G$-spaces, where the $G$-action on $Y$ is through $\lambda$, only because you're keeping track of $H$ as well.
Also,  the concept of a developing pair (often just developing map) of a $(G, X)$ manifold $M$ is an instance of this. This is a local diffeomorphism $\delta : \widetilde{M} \to X$ defined on the universal cover of $M$, and a group homomorphism $\rho : \pi_1(M) \to G$, for which $\delta$ is $\rho$-equivariant. You can see Chapter 3 of Thurston's 1997 book for information on this.

Maybe this answer has useful information for you?

I think Chapter 3 of Hsiang's Cohomology Theory of Topological Transformation Groups could be of interest to you, since it refers to "The Construction of A. Borel", and defines $h$-equivariant maps.

Thank you very much for the suggestions! Hsiang's text helped, although it also didn't contain many details.
